# The equivalent adjective for the noun "dive"

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage, adjectives

As you know a restaurant, hotel, bar, or place for entertainment or social activities that is unpleasant because of the condition of the building or the type of people that go there is called "dive" in informal English!

> **Example:** The place is a real **dive**, but the drinks are cheap and the food's great.

I need to know whether there is an adjectival equivalent for the noun "dive" in this sense in English.

I would call it a "low-class place" or "not classy place", but I have no idea if they sound idiomatic to you too.

I.e. I wonder what word can be used in the following sentence?

> That was a/an ............... place, but the drinks are cheap and the food's great.

### {Edit}

I think the safest way to convey my exact intention to the listener would be using "dive" in a noun form and just say:

> "this place / restaurant etc. is a (real) dive".

Comment: The most obvious choice is *divey*, but that's somewhat informal.

Comment: Relevant: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/375108/is-there-a-word-for-antro-in-english/375156#375156

Comment: That is an interesting thread @Cascavel, but the question is that why you did not mention the adjective "divey" in your confirmed answer? Although, I have no idea what "antro" means in Spanish.

Comment: You need a bit of US history.  Many night clubs are to be found in basements, DOWN a flight of steps.  It is probably  these that were originally called 'dives'.  They had the reputation of being sinful places, riddled with bootleged booze, crooks and sex, during the 'Prohibition' of 1020-33 (hence the reference to history).  As far as I know, there is no adjective.  Why?  Because the noun itself IS an attribute.  It's a dive.  Some people are gamblers, but there is no adjective for that, either.  You could coin one one: aleatorialistic, perhaps.  But why?

Comment: The adjective is *dive*. You can say *a dive bar, a dive restaurant, a dive motel,* and *a dive joint*. (Although I wouldn't say *dive place*, because *dive* means exactly the same thing and is shorter.)

Comment: Does it sound so bizarre if I use the noun "dive" as an attributive adjective and say e.g. "that was a dive cafe" that I need to avoid using it adjectivally @Peter Shor?

Comment: Related synonyms are *sketchy, grungy, questionable*.

Comment: Dive bars don’t have great food. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dive_bar_(drinking_establishment)

Comment: I would agree with @YosefBaskin Questionable seems to induce the same feeling as "Dive" to me. A dive is not only due to the interior, or styling of a place, it is more the overall atmosphere.

Comment: I'm tempted to suggest "divine", but I won't.

Comment: There are lots of picturesque adjectives like *sleazy*, *skeezy*, *skeevy*, or in UK *dodgy*, *seedy*, but beyond that the precise one would depend on things like what you wanted to emphasise, formality/register, dialect, whether you'd drink there, etc. *Squalid* or *insanitary* are stronger in condemnation. *Low-class* and other terms like *disreputable* have a similar meaning but are more prissy or negative in connotation than dive(y) - I can't imagine anyone would say a bar was *disreputable* or *low-class* outside of an old movie.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious choice is the adjective **divey,** [which as Wiktionary states](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/divey) is derived from the noun "dive" in the relevant sense.